# Use data from page one on page two

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a simple app which when someone clicks on a list element, a new page fires up with the text of the list element person clicked.

So I want the `device` variable to be passed to page called `deviceDetails`

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices" (click)="showDevice(device)">
    <ion-item>
      {{ device }}
      <!-- Whaetver device is clicked I want it to be in the ion-title on page 2 -->
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I think I should pass the data with `navController` in `showDevice()` method but I have no idea if `this.nav.push(deviceDetails,device);` works because I don't know how to get the data in `deviceDetails` page. Any ideas how to solve this?

Class that captures the data

```
export class DevicePage {
  device: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.device = navParams.get("deviceName");
    console.log(this.device);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DevicePage');
  }

}
```

@santosh singh explained to me in chat that I had to send the `deviceName` as an object like this.

```
showDevice(deviceName) {
  console.log(deviceName);
  this.navCtrl.push(DevicePage, { 'deviceName': deviceName });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data on `devicedetails` page as follow

```
 export class DeviceDetails{
    constructor(navParams: NavParams){
        this.deviceName= navParams.get("deviceName");

    }
}
```

In `showDevice` method

```
showDevice(devinceName){
      this.nav.push(DeviceDetails,{'deviceName':deviceName})
}
```

Comment: Would this be the right way to send the data? 

`this.navCtrl.push(DevicePage, deviceName);`

Comment: Would this have changed then? `this.device= navParams.get("device");`

Comment: Any idea why it's throwing undefined when I try to console log it?

Comment: Almost there. I just don't understand why it's undefined on the second page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163952/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-alex3wielki).